# How to Integrate SpagoBI application with Java Spring MVC Application?

Tags: spagobi

I want to open the spagoBI documents from spring MVC. Can any one explain the procedure to integrate SpagoBI application with Spring MVC?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Java-based SDK for SpagoBI.  You might create a controller (get reports / params list, execute SpagoBI documents) and view (select report, enter params, display report content) for SpagoBI

I recommend looking at the  [SpagoBI SDK Samples](http://forge.ow2.org/project/download.php?group_id=204&file_id=20384)
There is some [SDK Documentation](http://wiki.spagobi.org/xwiki/bin/view/spagobi_sdk/) as well.

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding to the question. I've small doubts like 1. Before trying to open the spagoBI document using java application, should we export those documents from spagoBI server?  2.Is it enough to include spagoBISDK jar file into library of java application or is it required to run the spagoBI server also parallelly?  Can u please specify the procedure briefly!!!

Comment: The spagobi SDK interacts with services provided by spagobi server. So yes, you must deploy (via spagobi studio) the reports/documents to Spagobi server in order to access them via the SDK(for example in a web application ).  You will need to run the spagobi server in tomcat, but you could even do that on the same tomcat instance as your web app (not necessarily best practice though).

Comment: Hi, I'm confused about how to use spagoBISDK for integration with spring MVC. Can you please tell me briefly in step by step.

Comment: Please look at the samples in the spagobi SDK. They are very helpful and functional.  What type of "integration" are you trying to accomplish with springmvc?

Comment: Hi, yes i've seen the spagoBISDK manual. Actually i want to open the spagoBI document by running springMVC application. So, is it enough to insert spagoBISDK jar file in java buildpath?

Comment: Hi, i've gone through the spagoBISDK samples as you have suggested. I've created the controller and could open loginTAG.jsp page but when i submit it, the documentsList.jsp is not opening. It's showing the exception :'org.apache.jasper.JasperException Unable to compile class for JSP'.  Moreover, in documentsList.jsp, under comments ,it says that  it is required to execute checkAuthentication() method. Please tell me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: I believe you're trying to attach your code to the samples in the SpagoBISDK.war.  

Study the examples / samples to understand the way they work and how they use the SDK. Then, see what parts you can re-use in your code.

I found it necessary to include these SpagoBI Jars. 
sbi.utils,
spago-core