# Integrate SpagoBI server with Java application with MySQL Db

Tags: java, spagobi

How to integrate SpagoBI server with Java application having MySQL Db? can someone give one example. 
I am having SpagoBi server running, I had created a cockpit using mysql DB in server.
How i will integrate, I don't have any idea. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Below links might help you:

[How to Integrate SpagoBI application with Java Spring MVC Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31115552/how-to-integrate-spagobi-application-with-java-spring-mvc-application)

http://www.spagoworld.org/jforum/posts/list/2024.page